# How to set and get hidden values from cell in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My JSON response for drop down:

```
{
    "projects": [
                 {
                     "id": 8,
                     "name": "Andriod APP",
                     "identifier": "andriod-app",
                     "description": "",
                     "status": 1,
                     "is_public": true,
                     "created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
                     "updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
                 },
                 ],
    "total_count": 8,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 25
}
```

I have a drop-down with button and table view in the table view cells. I have to show the projects name (requirement). If I select any projects name in the table view, it shown on the button. I can read the projects name. But I need to read the projects' Id also.

How it is possible to set and get the projects' id as hidden value for project names.

This is my piece of code:For showing the projects name in table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableString * text;
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:projectname]];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
}
```

Button action to show and hide the values from table view:

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
    NSString * projtitle = [(UIButton *) sender currentTitle];
    NSLog(@ " %@" , projtitle);
    if (self.tableView.hidden ==YES) {
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the Indexpath, then you can easily get the id from that, here below the code,

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender 
{
 CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_friend_list_table];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table_name indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

NSString *proj_id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForkey:@"id"]];
}
```

Note:
    you should store the data in array.

```
response=
{
 "projects": [
  {
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Andriod APP",
  "identifier": "andriod-app",
  "description": "",
  "status": 1,
  "is_public": true,
  "created_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z",
  "updated_on": "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z"
   },
   ],
  "total_count": 8,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 25
  }
```

Step 1:
    Store above json response to NSDictionary or NSArray. here i store it to NSArray.

```
 Ex:
     NSArray *response_arr=[response objectForKey:@"projects"];
```

Step 2:
    Use this response_arr load the tableview

Ex:

```
     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    if(tableView == self.tableView1) 
    { return [response_arr count];}
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 { 
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     } 
     if(tableView == self.tableView1)
     { 
        NSMutableString * text; 
        text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[response_arr objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
        cell.textLabel.text = text; 
     }

 }
```

Step 3:
     From DidSelect you can get the data's, here i store it to the dictionary. you should declare it globally,

Ex:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *data_dic;

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       { 
        if (tableView==self.tableView1)
         { 

            [self.btnoutlet1 setTitle:[[response_arr objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             self.tableView1.hidden = YES; 
    data_dic;=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  [data_dic setObject:[response_arr objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] forKey:@"data"];

         } 

       }
```

Step 4:
    Then you can get the data from dictionary inside the button action.

Ex

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender 
{
        NSString * projtitle = [(UIButton *) sender currentTitle];
        NSLog(@ " %@" , projtitle);
        NSString *projid= [data_dic objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"Id=%@",projid);

        if (self.tableView.hidden ==YES) {
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else {
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        }
 }
```

Comment: bro whta's the table_name  in indexpath

Comment: Its your actual tablename of your UITableView like  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *friend_list_table;

Comment: You should NEVER name a pointer 'id'. I suggest this be renamed *projectId

Comment: bro on cgpoint line it shows the error  " instance method- convertpointtoview not found (returntype defaults to id) "

Comment: I want to clarify the thing is "Did the button action from tableview or out of the tableview?"   If it is not subview of tableview it surely not work. Note this bro.

Comment: button action from out of the tableview bro

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView == self.tableView1)
{
return [myobject count];
}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
if(tableView == self.tableView1){
NSDictionary * tmpdict = [myobject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableString * text;

Comment: text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpdict objectForKeyedSubscript:projectname]
cell.textLabel.text = text;
}  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView==self.tableView1) {
UITableViewCell * Cell = [self.tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.btnoutlet1 setTitle:Cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.tableView1.hidden = YES;
}

Comment: - (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
NSString * projtitle = [(UIButton *) sender currentTitle];
NSLog(@ " %@" , projtitle);
UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"Selected button tag is %ld%", (long)selectedButton.tag);
 CGPoint buttonposition = [sender convertpoint:CGPointZero toView:_tableView1];
// NSIndexPath * indexpath = [_tableView1  indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonposition];
//  NSString * projid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@ " %@",[[myobject objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] objectForKeyedSubscript:projectid]];
if (self.tableView1.hidden ==YES) {
self.tableView1.hidden = NO;
}

Comment: @S.Karthik bro if i put like this then i got that above mentioned error is there any other ay to do this...easily..

Comment: what are the contents have the uitableviewcell like label? Do you have only label or uibutton too?

Comment: inside uitableviewcell it doesn't have any content...tableview and button are seperated.on button click it  hide and shows tableviewdatas...

Comment: So you can get the name from didselect right? then store the array in NSUserDefaults, then when you click the button, retrieve data from nsuser.

Comment: If you have still confusion may i share example code?

Comment: yeah first part is right...i get project name from didselect...during the selection...how do i get the projectid also...i don't know how to proceed this...that's my doubt? bro

Comment: http://imgur.com/htWMdit if u take a look at this image....you will get idea....in the project dropdown i shows the selected value android app during my selection i want to read the project id :8 also....how to do this?

Comment: k bro i will check this out let u know bro..thanks for help bro

Comment: bro it forms the data like this data = {      id= 8 } but if put  NSString *projid= [data_dic objectForKey:@"id"]; it shows nil...is it the right way to get id...or any correction needed.

Comment: Did you print the data_dic inside didselect? Is that have data?

Comment: {
    data =     {
        "created_on" = "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z";
        description = "";
        id = 8;
        identifier = "andriod-app";
        "is_public" = 1;
        name = "Andriod APP";
        status = 1;
        "updated_on" = "2015-06-29T11:54:23Z";
    };
}

Comment: this is the data inside that mutable dictionary

Comment: ohhh then you call like this friend, [[data_dic objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"];   Try and let me know once you get please

Comment: Did you get the answer please, check it as correct answer to close this question friend.

Comment: bro give your mail id....i want to know your professional information to update my self in ios development i am new to this.

Comment: Sure friend. karthik.sinfotech@gmail.com

Comment: bro is it possible to read the button's title value before onclick .?

Comment: ya sure. because in the viewdidload you should fix the title default.

Comment: my scenario is this....in that drop down i have to read the project name and project id details before the button is pressed....how to do this?

Comment: So when the user enter into the corresponding page what should be the button name?

Comment: btnaction1. is the name of the button....is it possible to get the projectid value from tableviewcell

Comment: bro i put those strings within the didrowselectatindexpath bro

Comment: bro on converting nsdata to nsstring   NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; on declaring this line it shows error like this novisible interface for nsstring declares initwithdata:encoding what's is the error...

Comment: NSError *error;
      NSData *jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:results options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
      if (error)
      {
      }
      else
      {
            json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsondata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: bro i will mail my requirement and what i had done till now..just guide me and share better ideas...bro..

Comment: projdict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[projdict setObject:[self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@" %@",projdict);
{
data ={
"created_on" = "2015-06-24T11:01:11Z";
description = "";
id = 3;
identifier = fotonation;
"is_public" = 1;
name = Fotonation;
status = 1;
"updated_on" = "2015-06-24T11:01:11Z";
};
}
projid = [[projdict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@ " %@" , projid);
3
projname = [[projdict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@ " %@" , projname);
Fotonation

Comment: test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:projid,proj_id, projname,proj_name, nil];
NSLog(@ " %@",test);
{
id = 3;
name = Fotonation;
}        
NSDictionary * test1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Project",test, nil];
NSLog(@" %@",test1);
{
{
id = 3;
name = Fotonation;
} = Project;
}

NSError * error;
NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test1 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];on nsdata i am getting error like invalid string format:
i want to get json format like : “project”:{“id”:”3”,”name”:”fotonation}

Answer (score 0):

As your id's type is a number,it can be set to button's tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest you to use Accessibility Identifier for the button,
you can fetch the identifier in same way as you have fetched the title of your button. Code for setting accessibility Identifier will look like.

```
[yourButton setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"Your project_id"];
```